# View my thread visitation history

Tags: feature-request, review-history

I often read through many threads and websites when trying to solve a problem, and only later realize that the first thing I read actually had the answer, or was key to eventually finding it (which is more often than not a SE thread).

Often I have closed the tab and forgotten the title of the thread, so I can't easily go back and upvote the question/answer, or I just plain forget to do so.

I think that if I could view my visitation history, I would upvote a lot more stuff. I can see a privacy concern with tracking this type of information, but I would find it useful. I suppose I could just filter my browser history, but I'm lazy and I'm probably not the only one.

Edit: I did notice the previous similar thread, but I decided to make this one because I want this feature for a specific purpose. It would also be useful to highlight in some way my most visited threads, but that would require keeping a history. So the first step would be to record that information.

Comment: It takes me about 5 seconds to get to my browser history and display only Stack Overflow posts. So either you're doing something very wrong or I really doubt this will save you a non-trivial amount of time. Or is the problem that you want to see more than the title of each page?

Comment: It's just that it's something that I have to think to do, it never even occurred to me until recently. If a history (or most visited) section appeared on the dashboard, I think it would remind people.
Also, I did notice the previous semi-duplicate thread. I made this one because I wanted to explain why I think that it would be beneficial to SE.

Comment: chrome://history

Comment: @OptimusPrime Ctrl+H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using the iOS app (not Android) you can see your history (of pages you viewed on the app) by opening the left menu and tapping on history, which opens something that looks like this:

> [image]

It seems like you’re not using the app, but it is an option to consider.

Comment: I'm not, but that is good to know.

Comment: There's no such feature on SE Android app, though I don't know if it's there on SO Android app (not that it matters since SO Android app has been removed from Google Play).

Comment: @Somewhat lol! Android app doesn't even have revisions, you want it to have history? The android app has 0 features, never had, since nobody was there to write any feature.